# How to structure classes in a C# program

Tags: c#, vsto

I have a VSTO (Excel) project written in C#.  Three questions:

1. I have a lot of variables that are populated once and then referenced extensively throughout the project.  So I created a public static class which I called "Omni" - since that is both descriptive and short.  Is something like this the recommended approach?
2. I put common functions in a public static class that I named "Utilities".  I then used the "this" keyword as the first parameter, making them extension methods.  They can then be accessed from anywhere - without using a "Utilities." prefix (although I'm not exactly sure why).  Same question: is this the preferred way of doing this?
3. Finally, I have some common 'subroutines', i.e., public void methods.  So parameters are passed in and processed, but nothing is returned.  Should such common code just go in its own appropriately named public static class and then get called with the class name as a prefix?  If so, is there any convention as to what the name of the class would be?

I realize these are newbie type questions (and I have been searching for a while!).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your points

> I have a lot of variables that are populated once and then referenced
>   extensively throughout the project. So I created a public static class
>   which I called "Omni" - since that is both descriptive and short. Is
>   something like this the recommended approach?

Yes, it is common practise to centralize for example string constants that
are often used.

If you have more of those, I would start to structure those to different
classes.

If you want that to be flexible and e.g. have cases where there are 
mappings between constants, like `Green = 1`, I would move to some
enumeration value technology. 
More on that idea can be found [in this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/stefansedich/enum-with-string-values-in-c)

If the value does not change between different starts of your application,
check if you can use resources for that, which is often a good choice
for string constants to.

> I put common functions in a public static class that I named
>   "Utilities". I then used the "this"  keyword as the first parameter,
>   making them extension methods. They can then be accessed from 
>   anywhere - without using a "Utilities." prefix (although I'm not
>   exactly sure why). Same question:  is this the preferred way of doing
>   this?

Extension methods are a handy way of getting things like conversions done.
Just do not everything as an extension, just conversions as a rule of thumb.

> Finally, I have some common 'subroutines', i.e., public void methods.
>   So parameters are passed in  and processed, but nothing is returned.
>   Should such common code just go in its own appropriately  named public
>   static class and then get called with the class name as a prefix? If
>   so, is there any convention as to what the name of the class would be?

This, in opposite of the others, looks like a design flaw.
Perhaps you can provide more information on what those subroutines do.

In object oriented code, code is distributed near the objects it is working
with. If you depend heavily on code that is in static classes, probably there
is something wrong. Do your static classes have members? Do they share some
knowledge between different calls to your static classes?

Comment: Re my first item, my Omni class **does** included any enumerations.  Most of the values stored there are obtained from external data sources (e.g., a list of product codes).

Comment: Re my first item, my Omni class **does** included any enumerations.  However, almost all of the values stored there are obtained from external data sources (e.g., a list of product codes).  Re my second item, they are generally **not** conversions.  An example would be a public static bool method called IsInCollection.  The parameters passed in are a collection and an item.  The method returns whether or not the given item is in the given collection.  If not handled as an extension method, what is the recommended way to do it?  Separate response to follow re my 3rd question(!)

Comment: Re my 3rd item, since it's essentially an Excel application, the classes correspond to Excel worksheets.  Within several I them I have common code that needs to be run.  But, of course, I only want it to appear in one place.  For example, in several sheets I have data returned from an SQL query that needs to populate the sheet and then be parsed, formatted, etc.  And the code is common - given the block of data returned, the sheet name, and the top left cell of the range where the data should be pasted.

Comment: Just some quick tips, because these questions are very broad: for item 2, and regarding your comment, check the [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx) method, it already does what you want. Rule 1 for Extension Methods: only write it if it applies to *all* values of your type, and in any context. You'll be pretty safe with that. Item 1: global static *constants* access classes are generally convenient and OK. Item 3: global static recurrent methods are generally OK too, for small projects. This can be a design smell on larger projects.